# Change number to corresponding letters

Tags: javascript

My question is how do I get the corresponding letter(s) from a number.

So

```
0    =>   0    // 0 stays 0
1    =>   A
2    =>   B
3    =>   C
26   =>   Z
27   =>   AA
28   =>   AB
55   =>   AC
702  =>   ZZ
```

The number will **definitely** not be over 702.

Is there some kind of method I can use to do this?

Comment: The method you can try is thinking hard on this problem first. Best of luck.

Comment: with only 702 items you could build an object and use it as a hashtable

Comment: @VishalDhawan, Isn't that a method **everybody** tries.

Comment: And @akaphenemom, I was kinda looking for a function instead of an object with 702 keys.

Comment: Divide your number by 26 + 1 (to account for the 0) and floor it. Use that to index into the string `"0ABC...XYZ"`. That's your first digit. Then modulo your number by 27 and index into the string again. That is your second digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the number into parts by doing a modulo by `26`, then use `String.fromCharCode` to convert it to a character:

```js
function numToExcelColumnName(n){
  if(!n) return 0

  n-- //Make 0 => A

  const lower = n % 26
  const upper = Math.floor(n / 26)
  
  return (
    upper 
      ? String.fromCharCode(65 + upper - 1) 
      : ''
  ) 
  + String.fromCharCode(65 + lower)
}
```

You can even extend this code to handle numbers above 702 as well by adding a loop:

```
function numToExcelColumnName(n){ 
  if(!n) return 0
    
  let output = ''
  while(n){
    n--
    output = String.fromCharCode(65 + n % 26) + output
    n = Math.floor(n / 26)
  }
  return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For single characters like A,B... you can get the number easily by

`num = ord(x)-65` where x is the corresponding character (A,B...)

For Double letters like (AB,BG,..)

`num = ord(str[0]-65)*26+(str[1]-65)` where str = xy where x and y are corresponding characters

Answer (score 0):

I liked the challenge, so I wrote the following code:

```
function NumbersToLetters(num) {
  var letArr=[];
  function numToLet(letterArray, number) {
    if(number>0) {
      var whole=Math.floor((number-1)/26);
      var reminder=(number-1)%26;
      letterArray.unshift(String.fromCharCode(65+reminder));
        numToLet(letterArray, whole);
    }
  };
  numToLetters(letArr, num);
  return letArr.length?letArr.join(""):"0";
}
```

To be used:

```
NumbersToLetters(num);
```